# Can I use SNMP over different protocol than UDP?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, snmp

I looking for an example of SNMP running in a protocol different than UDP. I need to argue with a professor who said that it's only possible to run SNMP over UDP. Anyone knows how it works in ATM? In my mind SNMP is a layer 7 protocol and doesn't matter what protocol is used for transport, but I only found references to UDP. Please post the references.

Comment: You can't compare ATM to UDP because ATM is a layer-1/2 protocol, while UDP is a layer-4 protocol. SNMP uses UDP, which can use ATM encapsulation at layer-2.

Comment: I don't know if your professor accepts Wikipedia... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol#Version_1 lists other protocls than UDP, like DDP, CLNS etc.

Comment: The question about ATM is about compatibility, I wasn't clear enough. About the Wikipedia's link it was useful for more research.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNMP of course can go over other protocols than UDP. For example, RFC 3430 defines SNMP over TCP,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3430

However, the widely used SNMP implementation is still UDP only in most cases, so rarely you see an application on TCP or other protocols (I knew some internal usage in Cisco).

Well, an argument is not really suggested, and hope you chat in a good manner with your professor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will be useful for my argue.

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 1157 'A Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP)' #4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157):

> Protocol Specification

> The network management protocol is an application protocol by which
> the variables of an agent's MIB may be inspected or altered.

> Communication among protocol entities is accomplished by the exchange
> of messages, each of which is entirely and independently represented
> within a single UDP datagram using the basic encoding rules of ASN.1
> (as discussed in Section 3.2.2). A message consists of a version
> identifier, an SNMP community name, and a protocol data unit (PDU).
> A protocol entity receives messages at UDP port 161 on the host with
> which it is associated for all messages except for those which report
> traps (i.e., all messages except those which contain the Trap-PDU).
> Messages which report traps should be received on UDP port 162 for
> further processing.

Comment: In the same RFC 1157 - 3.2.4  "Consistent with the goal of minimizing complexity of the management
   agent, the exchange of SNMP messages requires only an unreliable
   datagram service, and every message is entirely and independently
   represented by a single transport datagram.  While this document
   specifies the exchange of messages via the UDP protocol [11], the
   mechanisms of the **SNMP are generally suitable for use with a wide
   variety of transport services.**"